# How to prove these propositions?

Tags: number-theory

This is an exercise I don't quite know how to write in a acceptable mathematical form. (No, I haven't found a solution.)

"Prove that if $3 \mid n$ then $3 \mid n^2$.
And that if $3 \nmid n$ then $3 \nmid n^2$. (For the second part consider $n=3a+1$ and $n=3a+2$ in turn.)"

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

J

Comment: "I don't quite know how to write in a acceptable mathematical form." Does that mean you've figured it out, but you don't know how to write it in a mathematically rigorous way? If so, please edit your question and include what you have determined so far. In general, you should always indicate what you've tried when asking a question.

Comment: If you'd show us an attempt, we could aid you in refining it. What have you managed so far?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516658/proof-that-q2-is-indivisible-by-3-if-q-is-indivisible-by-3/516664#comment1106938_516664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $3\mid n$. Then $n=3q$ for some integer $q$. Hence $n^2=(3q)^2=9q^2=3(3q^2)$. Since $3q^2$ is an integer, $3\mid n^2$.

Comment: assume that 3∤n. Then n=3a+1 or n=3a+2, where a∈Z. 
Then n²=(3a+1)²= 9a²+6a+1=3(3a2+6a)+1. Because of the +1, you can conclude that it is not possible to have 3|n.
Same way with n=3a+2

Answer (score 0):

And for the second part, if $3\not\mid n$, then we would be able to express $n$ as $3a+1$ or $3a+2$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. We only discuss the case when $n=3a+1$, and the other case is similar.

Evaluate $n^2=(3a+1)^2=9a^2+6a+1 \equiv_3 1$. Therefore, it is clear that $3\not\mid n^2$. $\square$